# java.lang.NullPointerException on ATUReports.setWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

Is anyone else experience this? More importantly, anyone has a solution?

Using

- Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0), Build id: 20200910-1200
- JDK 1.8

I have updated all my maven dependencies:

- ATUReporter-Selenium-testNG    5.1.1
- ATUTestRecorder    2.1
- log4j-api  2.13.3
- log4j-core 2.13.3
- selenium-java  4.0.0-alpha-6
- selenium-server    4.0.0-alpha-2
- slf4j-api  2.0.0-alpha1
- slf4j-log4j12  2.0.0-alpha1
- testng 7.3.0
- webdrivermanager   5.2.0

And what worked before, now, isn't.

When I debug, I found that I am getting a NullPointerException on the line with the code.
`ATUReports.setWebDriver(driver);`

The console displays

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener.onFinish(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.invokeListeners(SuiteRunner.java:225)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:288)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at atu.testng.reports.writers.CurrentRunPageWriter.getTestCaseHTMLPath(Unknown Source)
    at atu.testng.reports.writers.CurrentRunPageWriter.writeFailedData(Unknown Source)
    at atu.testng.reports.writers.CurrentRunPageWriter.content(Unknown Source)
    at atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener.generateCurrentRunPage(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

I think that "... 12 more" might have more details, but not sure how to view it.

Workarounds are also welcome.

Comment: ...12 more means the remain 12 stack track is the same as the 12 stack trace of the above exception from bottom up.

Comment: Can you show your code? I believe you are passing null `drvier` reference to some method.

Comment: I placed `assertNotNull(driver);` before that statement to check that. So when debugging `driver` is not null.